# DC control using BJT

Tags: motor-controller

I have a DC motor control circuit as follows, but I don't understand its working principle.  Can you explain it to me?

[image]

Comment: Did you come up with that circuit yourself, or did you copy it from somewhere?

Comment: Which bits do you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input is through an optoisolator, a positive signal lights the LED which causes the photo-transistor to turn on. The photo-transistor is connected as a common collector amplifier, the more light on it the higher the voltage at the emitter, which is connected to the base of Q2.

Q2 is a common emitter NPN amplifier, so when it's base goes more positive it's collector voltage goes down and pulls the base of Q1, a common emitter PNP amplifier, lower. Being a PNP, a lower base voltage turns it on more allowing the supply voltage, Vcc, to pass through to the motor, powering it.

The diode D1 across the motor is to reduce any back EMF from the motor, since the windings are inductors they produce a reversed polarity voltage when voltage to them is switched on and off, and the diode shorts out this voltage so it doesn't damage the driving transistor Q1.